# Serving files - which way to choose - direct urls or controller which returns a response

Tags: php, image, optimization, apache2, serve

So I'm creating a project which will include and serve a lot of images. The images are located in the server which runs apache2. I will be using php 7.4/8. My question is which way is faster - to directly serve images - domain.com/uploads/2021/images/image_1.jpeg or to use some controller which reads and servers images - domain.com/images/2021/images/image_1.jpeg

The second option won't do any scaling nor manipulation of the image, but in this case, the images will be stored in the db as hashed values and it will read from there in order to know which file contents to serve as image_1.jpeg.

Comment: Whenever you can cut out a middle man, it will almost always speed things up. Apache is going to serve everything, no matter what, so having PHP do anything is just extra work.

Comment: Take CDN as an example. It's good to let them do the work for you. A good read https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/. I also believe there should be an Amazon service for this which you can opt for.

Comment: If you want your images to be available for certain users(only logged in user). Then in your controller check your user logged in or not. If not logged in don't send the image else send.

If the above scenario not a case for you. Then don't read and serve images in your back end. It will increase you server recourses.